# Unwanted white space on right of website html/css

Tags: html, css, hide, overflow, hidden

So I have tried to get rid of this white space to the right of my website for ages now. I've tried all the overflow-x: hidden rules but none of them seem to work.

I have ruled it down to when I remove:

```
(div id="content5" style="position:absolute;")
(img style="width:175px; height:175px;" src="Images/Graphic.jpg")
(/div)
```

from the html file then the white space goes away. How do I put the picture on my web page without getting the white space? Don't worry I am using angle brackets for my html.

You can view [my website here](http://www.danielravens.co.uk/NewWebsite/index.html).

CSS:

view code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao34bzawp9zgviw/Untitled-1.jpg?dl=0)

HTML:

view code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bck81bylsvqp2d/Untitled-2.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: dont worry, just paste ur css and script that you think is the problem  to ease us to check here

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot of your problem? I can't seem to see a white space to the right on your website.

Comment: I can't see a whitespace either. Don't worry, your webpage is fine ;-)

Comment: What browser are you all viewing this in? I was able to recreate the extra margin in Chrome.

Comment: and I was not friends, what gives ???, what where are you seeing this ???

Comment: I included a screenshot of what I see in Chrome and what fixes it. All of the page elements that you see have a position absolute and height and width of 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the width of the #content5 element set to the pixel width of the image:

```
#content5 {
  width:175px;
}
```

Right now, the width is set to 50%. But that essentially sets it to 50% of the width of the parent element, which is the whole page. If you look in the inspector, the divs containing all of your images are much larger than they need to be because of this.

EDIT: Included inspector image of Chrome session
[image: Evidence of OPs issue]

Comment: Such a simple fix, I can't believe I missed that! The help was much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Ravens if you insert the following code it should fix your problem:

```
html { 
  background: url(Images/FrontCover.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This code basically stretches everything on the page to make it fit I got this code from the following site: 
[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)